# Code runs in Google Collab but not on local machine python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, tensorflow, keras

I'm running a TensorFlow model and when I try to run it on google collab it runs fine but if I run the same code on my local machine it gives me the following error:

```py
C:\Users\Shaikh Abuzar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py:1472: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm_var_1.py", line 363, in <module>
    callbacks=[es], steps_per_epoch= len(generator_train_var))
  File "C:\Users\Shaikh Abuzar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kerashypetune\kerashypetune.py", line 460, in search
    **all_fitargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shaikh Abuzar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shaikh Abuzar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 876, in fit
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "C:\Users\Shaikh Abuzar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 365, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "C:\Users\Shaikh Abuzar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py", line 1485, in on_epoch_end
    self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
  File "C:\Users\Shaikh Abuzar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1519, in set_weights
    if expected_num_weights != len(weights):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

If anyone can help me it would be really great.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kQ2KeiSXEbLRJ3tooJ8A6-tg0oqmNBRR?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check what `weights` is.

Comment: There is no variable named `weights`.